# Programación Android: Restringir el uso de una app a móviles

Tags: android

Estoy empezando a trabajar con Android y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de impedir que mi aplicación se instale en tablets, es decir, quiero hacer una aplicación que solo sirva para teléfonos Android.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si tu app la diseñas con directivas Material Design, ya tiene en cuenta diferente tamaños de pantalla, el contenido y elementos se deben adaptar a las pantallas tanto de Smartphone como Tablet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la directiva [compatible-screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) en el `manifest.xml`

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

pero puede que las `phablets` queden también excluidas.

Otra manera seria requerir el permiso de Teléfono que sea obligatorio.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que menciona el señor Mark Murphy en su [**respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25230624/250260) de como restringir la instalación de una aplicación por medio de la detección de su tamaño podría considerarse correcta :

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Pero desde mi punto de vista no del todo cierto ya que si quieres restringir la instalación unicamente para telefonos y si consideramos que un telefono define tener soporte telefonico entonces lo correcto seria requerir como caracteristica que tenga soporte telefonico.

**Hay que recordar que actualmente existen dispositivos por ejemplo de 7 pulgadas que también cuentan con soporte telefonico.**