# Cómo limitar el uso de mi App a ciertos dispositivos

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

¿Cómo puedo limitar el uso de mi App a ciertos dispositivos?

Por ejemplo, que sólo sea utilizada por celulares (no por tablets) y aquellos celulares de una determinada resolución de pantalla (si es posible mayor a una determinada).

Vi una pregunta [parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16435/programaci%C3%B3n-android-restringir-el-uso-de-una-app-a-m%C3%B3viles), pero al intentar utilizar su respuesta no funcionó, más que nada quiero saber si existe algún nuevo método o algo, porque el hacer la App para diferentes dispositivos me está volando la cabeza en términos de diseño.

Comment: Quizas deberías usar algo como diseño Adaptable para Android. Hay varios plugins que te permiten hacerlo, yo no suelo preocuparme mucho de eso pero sí es importante. Hay una librería que se llama flexbox en android. La cual implementa las propiedades flexbox del css a android https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout tutorial. https://www.raywenderlich.com/179-adaptive-ui-tutorial-for-android-with-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

En el manifest puedes declarar que la app requiere llamadas con :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```

Otra manera es limitando el tamaño de la pantalla:

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
   </compatible-screens>
```

Aquí tienes la explicación completa
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution